# Canon EDSDK recording for more than 30 minutes

Tags: c++, canon-sdk

I have a canon camera and I am using Canon's EDSDK to render live video to a PC. I know that DSLRs can't record for more than 30 mins, so is there a way to use the SDK to allow the camera to break that 30 minute barrier?

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible, this is a limit built into the camera and/or a file system limit and cannot be circumvented with the SDK.

you might have better luck with something like Magic Lantern if your camera is supported. Have a look at this [FAQ entry](http://wiki.magiclantern.fm/faq#how_do_i_record_for_more_than_12_minutes)

> **How do I record for more than 12 minutes?**
>
> **H.264:**
>
> - Lower the `bitrate`_ (CBR 0.4 will let you record continuously for 30 minutes).
> - Use `Movie restart`_, but you will lose a few seconds when a new file is created.
> - Technically, there's no 12 minute limit. There's a 30 minute limit and a 4 GB limit, whichever comes first. With default bitrate settings, the 4 GB limit is reached after around 12 minutes (more or less).
>
> **RAW:**
>
> - Can record continuously until the card gets full (no 30-minute limit).
> - File sizes are huge; you may want to reduce resolution and/or FPS; also use a large card.
> - exFAT recommended; otherwise, when creating a new 4GB segment, the speed drops a bit and recording may stop.
>
> **External HDMI recorder:**
>
> - Enable the Clear Overlays feature to hide the focus box and the 16:9 bars.
> - Make the half-shutter button sticky (Prefs menu) to prevent the camera from turning off LiveView after 30 minutes.